# Include CakePHP components only if the request is not AJAX?

Tags: ajax, cakephp, components, cakephp-1.3

Is it possible to tell CakePHP to load different components/helpers based on whether the request is AJAX or not?

Obviously you can't use RequestHandler::isAjax, since RequestHandler itself is a component!

My concern is performance - am I right to think that loading up all the components (I have about 4-6 in most controllers) is going to be a drag on speed?

One idea I thought of was to create an AjaxController, with minimal components and no helpers, but this seems a bit dirty?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the RequestHandlerComponent by default and let it load the other components if needed. Loading just the RH component won't affect your system. You shouldn't be trying micro optimize this stuff right away in any case.

Also, depending on what kind of JS setup you have, most JS libraries send a `X-Requested-With` with the value set to `XMLHttpRequest`. You could look for that as well.

Personally, I think the `RequestHandlerComponent` is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks, on your advice I've included only RequestHandlerComponent and no helpers.  In AppController::beforeFilter, I check the request type and if it is not ajax, load the components and helpers I need.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried this?

[Adding Components on the fly](http://josediazgonzalez.com/2009/08/14/adding-a-helper-behavior-component-on-the-fly/)